# скрыть вкладку notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

Вот я в tkinter создаю вкладку, а возможно ли ее скрывать (не удаляя)?
Например скрыть вторую и все элементы находящиеся в том frame.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook

window = Tk()
tab_control = Notebook(window)
tab1 = Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='один')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='два')

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
window.mainloop()
```

Я так понимаю через его id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tab_control.hide(tab1)`  скрыть `tab_control.select(tab1)` показать